# Moving elements from one array to another in order that can repeat (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I'm trying to make a function that will take the first element from one array and move it to another array (goes through the whole array doing this), and then when the first array's length becomes zero, everything goes back to where it was originally: All the elements in the first array, nothing in the second. I have this `while` loop that does everything as intended, however I need the `break` statement so that it doesn't log them all in one go. I can't figure out a way to get it to repeat while still having the `break` at the end of the `while` loop. Any help would be appreciated!

Here is my code so far:

```
const moveToArray = (arr1, arr2) => {  
  while (arr1.length) {
  console.log(arr1[0]);
  arr2.push(arr1.shift());
  break;
  }
  if (!arr1.length) {
    arr1 = arr2;
    arr2 = [];
    }
  }
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to use the [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) ?

Comment: can you provide some example input and expected output results?

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code -

1. you call `break` in the `while` loop without any condition so only the loop only runs once
2. reassigning `arr1 = arr2` and `arr2 = []` does not work like you think it does

Anyway none of that matters. The answer is to use `splice` -

```js
const moveToArray = (arr1, arr2) =>
  arr1.splice(0, 0, ...arr2.splice(0, arr2.length))
  
const x = [1,2,3]
const y = [4,5,6]

moveToArray(x, y)
console.log("x:", JSON.stringify(x))
console.log("y:", JSON.stringify(y))
```

```
x: [4,5,6,1,2,3]
y: []
```

If you need intermediate results, I would also recommend using a generator, but not as Flying Potato Chip suggests -

```js
function* moveToArray (arr1, arr2)
{ while (arr1.length)
  { yield [arr1, arr2]
    arr2.push(arr1.shift())
  }
  arr1.splice(0, 0, ...arr2.splice(0, arr2.length))
  yield [arr1, arr2]
}

const x = [1,2,3]
const y = [4,5,6]

for (const [xstep, ystep] of moveToArray(x, y))
  console.log("step:", JSON.stringify(xstep), JSON.stringify(ystep))

console.log("x:", JSON.stringify(x))
console.log("y:", JSON.stringify(y))
```

```
step: [1,2,3] [4,5,6]
step: [2,3] [4,5,6,1]
step: [3] [4,5,6,1,2]
step: [4,5,6,1,2,3] []
x: [4,5,6,1,2,3]
y: []
```

Answer (score 0):

[Generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) /
[yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) /
[function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*) / [function* expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function*)

I'm a little confused...

what you say here

> everything goes back to where it was originally

but you also say

> All the elements in the first array, nothing in the second

I really don't know what you trying to do
and you don't give us any example
so this is my final guess

```
start
arr1[1, 2, 3], arr2[4, 5, 6]

extract value: 1, arr1[2, 3], arr2[4, 5, 6, 1]
extract value: 2, arr1[3], arr2[4, 5, 6, 1, 2]
extract value: 3, arr1[], arr2[4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
// you need arr2 as result? and extract value from arr 1?

// but arr1 and arr2 is untouched?
end
arr1[1, 2, 3], arr2[4, 5, 6], result: [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3]
```

then what you need is use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to make an object copy
instead of references
Object.assign() will creat a new object that is not references
so manipulate what it creat will not effect the original object

thanks for the advice about use `for..of`
I have edited it to a cleaner version

```js
// function* means it's a generator function
// you can't use this at arrow function
// generator function will pause and return the value where the yield is
// use next() to get next iteration
// here I just return both array
function* moveToArray(arr1, arr2) {
    arr1 = Object.assign([], arr1);
    arr2 = Object.assign([], arr2);
    while (arr1.length) {
        let extract = arr1.shift();
        arr2.push(extract);
        yield [extract, arr2];
    }
}
let a1 = [1, 2, 3];
let a2 = [4, 5, 6];
let result = [];

console.log(`start: arr1[${a1}], arr2[${a2}]`);

for (let [arr1_first_value, combined_arr] of moveToArray(a1, a2)) {
    console.log(`yield: arr1_first_value[${arr1_first_value}], combined_arr[${combined_arr}]`);
    result = combined_arr;
}
// no need to put it back because original object is untouched
console.log(`end: arr1[${a1}], arr2[${a2}], result:[${result}]`);
```

Comment: it is recommended to use `for..of` to iterate through a generator when possible. see my answer for a demonstration

Comment: wow, I didn't realize you could just use generator in the for...of

Comment: happy to share! `for..of` works on any object that implements [Symbol.iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator), which includes generators :D Working with iterators directly via `.done`, `.value`, and `.next()` is needed for sophisticated behaviours but is a bit cumbersome and can easily introduce bugs.

Answer (score -2):

Try the following.

```
const moveToArray = async (arr1, arr2) => {  
  while (arr1.length) {
  console.log(arr1[0]);
  arr2.push(arr1.shift());
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 2000));
  }
  if (!arr1.length) {
    arr1 = arr2;
    arr2 = [];
    }
  }
```

Comment: @parallax_c 'break' in your code will terminate your loop at first iteration.